# Get icon process from HWND, process name OR other process identifier

Tags: c++, process, icons, handle

I have the process name and the handle (HWND) of its window. 
**I want now to get the relative icon (if available)**. 
 Searching through MSDN, I found `ExtractIcon()` to get the handle to the icon from a given exe name, and `GetIconInfo()` to get "information" of the icon from the `HICON`. 
I don't know if it's the right way to do this, and how to retrieve correct information to show (in a second moment) the icon without the handle to the icon.
I have to send this information to another process (through socket) that has to show the icon.
In the `ICONINFO` structure there are `HBITMAP` fields that contains the bitmap (black&white and with colour). Is it useful?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the API GetClassLong to retrieve the icon associated with your program then use SendMessage API passing the hwnd of of the window you want to change it's icon.

in this Example I extracted the icon from my application then set it to Calculator. my windows calculator is open before sending to it the icon:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // just for explanation so left clicking in your client area and see the result
{
    HICON icon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICON);
    HWND hCons = FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator"); // I already opened windows calculator. you can use any other window but be sure to get its valid Handle
    if(!hCons)
        MessageBox(0, "\"Calculator\" windows is not found!", 0, MB_OK|MB_ICONHAND);
    SendMessage(hCons, WM_SETICON, (WPARAM)ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)icon); // setting the icon

}
break;
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I can send the icon variable through socket to another program (which run on another computer)? Because I need to send it in this way.

Comment: use socket file transfer then.

Comment: Sorry it sounds stupid, I want to understand if with HICON I have an handle to the icon or the icon itself: if I have an handle, like pointers, in another PC it could point to another object. Otherwise I have the object and it would works.

Comment: So who receive the HICON through the socket could draw it. Thank you! I'll try to make it work.

Comment: no you can't you have to do serialization/deserialization on both sides client and server to send and receive icon. another thing HICON is just a handle to the ICON. the real icon is in memory/hard disk... to send it retrieve first its bits through functoin: `GetBitmapBits` then send

Comment: in fact you cannot send a handle to an icon: HICON or to a cursor HCURSOR or to a bitmap HBITMAP... through sockets.  because Theses handles do have meanings to your application only. other "remote" applications and processes can make no sense of it nor use them. Since a handle is really only a 32 bit value there is a decent chance the remote PC already has a handle with that value using a totally different meaning.
you can use GetDIBits() API to store the icon's  bits in  a buffer then send. Good Luck